# A meta-meta-Riley

Tags: riddle, wordplay, steganography

Read:
$\phantom{/a/}$

> My pre**f***i*x deter*m*ines$\phantom{q}$
>   My su**f**fix, a *g*ro*u***p**
>   My infix blunde*r*s
>   My whole will **c**onfuse

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> Loops

The riddle:

> The italics spell imgur and the bolds and phantoms added make for https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifNeG.jpg, which leads to another riddle (what I suspect is the real riddle):
> My prefix, exclaimed when interested
> My suffix, exclaimed when mistaken
> My infix, exclaimed when amazed
> My whole, what this all is

Prefix:

> "Lo" exclaims interest

Suffix:

> "Oops" exclaims a mistake

Infix:

> "Oo" exclaims amazement

Whole:

> The link in the image (tinyurl.com/unknot1232) loops back to here

---

Original riddle is:

> Deterrent

Prefix:

> "det" like determinant

Suffix:

> "ent"? Not sure here. Word could also be deterrence or deterring but I'm still confused

Infix:

> "err" is to make a mistake

Whole:

> The first riddle is a deterrent for the second puzzle

Comment: Got it! :) One extra hint: "unknot" is simply a closed loop in mathematics. I will accept your answer after the original Riley riddle is figured out

Comment: @thecoder16 Added a guess for the first riddle!

Comment: You got part of it... not quite :)

Answer (score 4):

It is:

> Minecraft  [image] the address is made up of letters in bold and italics

prefix:

> deter**mine**s => Mine

suffix:

> group => craft

infix:

> nec => a bit political - NEC - National Executive Comitee

whole:

> I'm not sure why should it confuse anyone, but maybe because it is based on cubes or because the name of the game is a bit ambiguous...

---

EDIT (the original riddle):

You are:

> reference

Your prefix:

> refere(e) who determines the outcome of a game or just the verb refer

Your sufix:

> CE for Casual Encounters :D

Your infix:

> er(r) => blunders

Your whole:

> I don't have to say that reference confuses, especially this one.

Comment: You’ve got the right idea, unfortunately new imgur addresses are a bit different: imgur.com/a/xxxxx

Comment: Added an answer for the original riddle.

Comment: Not quite - but you got one of the parts

Answer (score 4):

The first riddle's solution is

> (Red) Herring

Read:

> Past tense is pronounced "Red"

My prefix determines

> Might be "He", might be "Her" - determines a gender.

My suffix, a group

> "Ring".  [A ring is an abelian group with a second binary operation that is *(blah blah maths ...)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

My infix blunders

> "Err"

My whole will confuse

> A red herring is an element of a puzzle designed to put you off track.

Comment: Yep, got it :) Though for the suffix they are also synonyms, no maths required